# Not sure how to make the correct mySQL query to get data from multiple tables in 1 query

Tags: mysql, database

I need to get data from multiple tables from a database and I need to use 1 query, but I can't get it to work.

I got these table:
**projects:**

```
id    name        start_date           end_date             project_leader    finished
1     project_1   2012-08-01 00:00:00  2012-29-01 00:00:00  2                 0
```

**users**

```
id    username    password    email      status
1     user_1      pass_1      email_1    1
2     user_2      pass_2      email_2    1
```

**user_has_project**

```
userid   projectId
1        1
```

**tasks**

```
id   project  description          end_date               user
1    1        test description 1   2012-29-01 00:00:00    1
2    1        test description 2   2012-29-01 00:00:00    1
```

So what I need to do, is make a query that should give me this result:
**Result:**

```
project_id  project_name    start_date           end_date             project_leader    finished       tasks
1           project_1       2012-08-01 00:00:00  2012-29-01 00:00:00  user_2            0              2
```

I got it to work until the part where I need to count the amount of tasks that a project has.
I got this query, but that doesn't work:

```
SELECT projects.id, projects.name, projects.start_date, projects.end_date,
       projects.finished, users.username AS project_leader, COUNT(tasks.id) AS tasks
FROM projects, tasks
INNER JOIN user_has_project ON user_has_project.projectId = projects.id
INNER JOIN users ON projects.project_leader = users.id
WHERE user_has_project.userId = 1
```

SQL dump, so people can try to test their query for me:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Machine: localhost
-- Genereertijd: 20 aug 2012 om 19:42
-- Serverversie: 5.5.16
-- PHP-Versie: 5.3.8

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `project-deadline`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `projects`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_leader` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `finished` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `projects`
--

INSERT INTO `projects` (`id`, `name`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `project_leader`, `finished`) VALUES
(1, 'Project 1', '2012-08-01 00:00:00', '2012-09-18 00:00:00', 1, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `tasks`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `status`, `timezone`) VALUES
(1, 'DijkeMark', '37540da17c71d40c656b97b32c00f692', 'mark.dijkema@gmail.com', 1, 'UP1');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `user_has_project`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_has_project` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `projectId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`projectId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `user_has_project`
--

INSERT INTO `user_has_project` (`userId`, `projectId`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 6);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Can you provide us a SQL script to recreate part of your database (structure and data) on our own server to test the queries?

Comment: Okay, I added the sql dump in my main post

Comment: In the dump you added the `tasks` table is empty, so it is no wonder that your query (and mine, which is based on yours) returns an empty result set, it would be in fact the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT projects.id,
        projects.name,
        projects.start_date,
        projects.end_date,
        projects.finished,
        users.username AS project_leader,
        COUNT(tasks.id) AS tasks
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN tasks ON (tasks.project = projects.id)
JOIN user_has_project ON (user_has_project.projectId = projects.id)
JOIN users ON (projects.project_leader = users.id)
WHERE user_has_project.userId = 1
GROUP BY projects.id
```

Comment: Sorry mate, but this one doesn't work. It gives an empty result.

Comment: I verified the query and it should be correct, but without some database on which to try it I cannot fully verify it. Can you provide us a small sql script to recreate at least a small part of your DB (structure and data) on which try the query?

Comment: Given that your `tasks` table is empty in the dump you gave us, the empty result is actually correct. I modified the query using a `LEFT JOIN` on the `tasks` table so that if it is empty it should still work, please try it now. @DijkeMark

Comment: This works. Thank you so much. I still need to work on my mySQL skills. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use Aggregate function i-e COUNT() with other cols, you have to use group by clause. And one more thing, I have also modeified the query as following;
Also remember to use HAVING clause instead of WHERE clause whenever you want to filter something from GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT projects.id, projects.name, projects.start_date, projects.end_date,
       projects.finished, users.username AS project_leader, COUNT(tasks.id) AS tasks
FROM projects 
INNER JOIN user_has_project ON user_has_project.projectId = projects.id
INNER JOIN users ON user_has_project.userid = users.id
INNER JOIN tasks ON users.id = task.user
GROUP BY projects.id, projects.name, projects.start_date, projects.end_date, 
         projects.finished, project_leader
HAVing user_has_project.userid = 1
```

**NOTE:** please modify this query according to your need, I think this will difinitly work for you.

Comment: It gives me this error: #1054 - Unknown column 'user_has_project.userId' in 'having clause'

Comment: I missed type the cols name i-e 'user_has_project.userid' check for all the cols name I typed carefully